# Google maps asynchronous loading streetview

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, bind

Is there any way how to get event when marker opened? In map I have about two thousands markers and each have own streetview in infobox. Streetview have source in google api, so page loading is too slow (2000+ streetview images loading in one moment). There is something like this (asynchronous loading)?

```
$(window).bind('eventWhenMarkerWasOpened', function(){
   $('#infowindow').append('<img src="here is path to streetview google api" />');
});
```

Comment: Why do you download the streetview images before the marker is clicked?  What do you mean by "marker opened"? How is it "opened"? By clicking? By mouseover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a domready-event for the infobox that should be a good place to extend the contents of the infobox:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoboxObject, 
                              'domready', 
                               function(){/*do something*/});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using FusionTableLayers instead of normal markers?
FusionTables enables you to load the tons of markers quickly, and you can use a few SQLs.

```
var infoWnd, map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523),
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
      mapOptions);

  infoWnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: '\'Geocodable address\'',
      from: '1mZ53Z70NsChnBMm-qEYmSDOvLXgrreLTkQUvvg'
    },
    suppressInfoWindows : true
  });
  layer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", onLayerClicked);
}

function onLayerClicked(evt) {
  var imgUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?" +
                "size=400x300&" +
                "sensor=false&" +
                "location=" + evt.latLng.toUrlValue();
  infoWnd.setPosition(evt.latLng);
  infoWnd.setContent("<img src='" + imgUrl + "'>");
  infoWnd.open(map);
  return false;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for ans, but Dr.Molle have solution what is better for my case. And this is awesome solution too..